# XSLT group select when not all nodes have the value

Tags: xml, xslt

First of all I use xlst 1.0.

I have some structure:

```
<Users>
    <User name="Alex" surname="Jones"/>
    <User name="Mary" surname="Jones"/>
    <User name="Jane" surname="Wolf"/>
    <User name="John" />
</Users>
```

Now I need to make from this.

```
<Families>
    <Family surname="Jones">
         <Name>Alex</Name>
         <Name>Mary</Name>
    </Family>
    <Family surname="Wolf">
         <Name>Jane</Name>
    </Family>
    <Family surname="No surname">
         <Name>John</Name>
    </Family>
</Families>
```

When I use `<xslt:key...>` It only shows users that have surname.

Comment: Why don't you post your styleheet (preferably minimized to only what's necessary) so that we have something to work with.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, this is only simple example, me stylesheet much more complex, Ill try to put some minimized, but later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use <s>an empty string</s> a non-value as the value of a key. Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="user-by-surname" match="User" use="@surname" />

<xsl:template match="/Users">
    <Families>
        <xsl:for-each select="User[generate-id()=generate-id(key('user-by-surname', @surname)[1])]">
            <Family surname="{@surname}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('user-by-surname', @surname)"/>
            </Family>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="User[not(@surname)]">
            <Family surname="no surname">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="User[not(@surname)]"/>
            </Family>
        </xsl:if>
    </Families>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="User">
    <Name><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></Name>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "You cannot use an empty string as the value of a key" is wrong, you need to compute the key value with an expression that evaluates to a non-empty node-set or a primitive value but that value can be the empty string so doing `<xsl:key name="user-by-surname" match="User" use="string(@surname)" />` is possible.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for the correction. Nevertheless, my suggested code remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative here is a sample using the empty string as a key value for elements not having a `surname` attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="user-by-surname" match="User" use="string(@surname)" />

  <xsl:template match="/Users">
    <Families>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="User[generate-id()=generate-id(key('user-by-surname', string(@surname))[1])]"/>
    </Families>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="User[string(@surname) = '']">
    <Family surname="No surname">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('user-by-surname', string(@surname))" mode="item"/>
    </Family>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="User">
    <Family surname="{@surname}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('user-by-surname', string(@surname))" mode="item"/>
    </Family>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="User" mode="item">
    <Name>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </Name>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```